# How can I configure Ansible to output errors without replaced newlines?

Tags: ansible

It seems that ansible return results using JSON format, replacing the newlines with `\n` in the output.

This makes very hard to read the output on the screen / logs. How can I configure it to use real-newlines?

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the callback plugins in your `ansible.cfg` file...

```
[defaults]
(...)
stdout_callback=debug
```

Will solve your issue... Don't ask why it's not the default, because I really can't say.

**NOTE**: This is only available in Ansible `2.0.0` and later.

Answer (score 0):

Use `from_json` filter

```
  tasks:
    - name: Execute the command/script
      shell: <some command>
      register: result
    - debug: var=result.stdout | from_json
```

Comment: I think he's looking for normal errors, not adding debug to potential error. Wish I knew the answer too. :)

Comment: If I'm using roles in ansible galaxy, I don't have access to their tasks -- i want to do this globally for a role